# Django - go to #id tag inside HTML

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

From views.py, is there any way to make it go to an id tag inside HTML?

For example,

my html:
    `<body>
      <div id="lotofstuff"> content </div>
      <div id="pictures"> content </div>
    </body>`

On special cases, I want the response to go to http://www.url.com#pictures, so it goes to the middle of the page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without redirecting I would set a variable in your view and pass it to your template.

```
gotodiv = False
if somecase:
    gotodiv = 'pictures'
```

Then, in your template, have some simple javascript to go to the div.

```
{% if gotodiv %}
<script> window.location.hash = '#{{gotodiv}}'; </script>
{% endif %}
```

No extra hits on your webserver or django app.

*Edited to make location.hash dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if from a view this is possible (maybe yes), but the simplest way I can imagine of is using redirect from Template, so you may have:

```
YourView:
 [...]
 if condition1:
  context.update('center_in_the_middle':True)
 else:
  context.update('center_in_the_middle':False)
[...]
```

And then in the templates:
template0.html

```
{% if center_in_the_middle %}
  [redirect to URL1]
{% else %}
  [redirect to URL2]
{% endif %}
```

Hope it helps!